# Install scripts in alternate directory using ExtUtils::MakeMaker

Tags: perl, debian, makemaker

I have an ExtUtils::MakeMaker makefile that installs two scripts `script1` and `script2`. I do this using the line

```
EXE_FILES => ['usr/sbin/script1',
              'usr/sbin/script2', ],
```

in `Makefile.PL`. However, when `make install` is run the two scripts are installed in `/usr/bin` whereas I would like them installed in `/usr/sbin`.

Note that this is all being done inside of a Debian package, so I am looking for a way of specifying the script installation directory inside of `Makefile.pl` (or `debian/rules`) rather than from the command line. 
How do I tell MakeMaker to install these files in `/usr/sbin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say `EXE_FILES` is

> Ref to array of executable files. The files will be copied to the `INST_SCRIPT` directory.

So

```
perl Makefile.PL INST_SCRIPT=/usr/sbin
```

Comment: Do you have any advise for installing some scripts in /usr/sbin and some others in /usr/bin ?

Comment: @Nuxwin, I doubt there's any support for that, so you'd probably have to make custom Makefile rules